# can we solve duplicate numbers in multidimentional array with new Set?

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, multidimensional-array, duplicates

here I want to ask about the unique/duplicate numbers in multidimensional arrays, 
can we use the method of `new Set` to solving the vertical and horizontal of the multidimensional array to fill numbers from 1-9 I those values are duplicate and have `0` number inside? 
this seems like a Sudoku game, I was thinking for solve Sudoku game using `new Set` but if I using it, it gonna change the position of values in the index if the numbers are duplicate,

how can we fill the `0` number in the multidimensional array with which numbers not in same with that row and columns? 
is that possible using the `new Set` method for solving this ? for Sudoku game?

```js
let nums = [ [ 1, 0, 5, 8, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0 ],
  [ 0, 9, 0, 0, 7, 6, 4, 0, 5 ],
  [ 2, 0, 0, 4, 0, 0, 8, 1, 9 ],
  [ 0, 1, 9, 0, 0, 7, 3, 0, 6 ],
  [ 7, 6, 2, 0, 8, 3, 0, 9, 0 ],
  [ 0, 0, 0, 0, 6, 1, 0, 5, 0 ],
  [ 0, 0, 7, 6, 0, 0, 0, 3, 0 ],
  [ 4, 3, 0, 0, 2, 0, 5, 0, 1 ],
  [ 6, 0, 0, 3, 0, 8, 9, 0, 0 ] ]

 for(let i = 0 ; i < nums.length ; i++){
   let check = [...new Set(nums[i])]
    console.log(check)
 }
```

those are the data and if I using newSet it gonna just unique numbers, but and i want to fill the 0 number with the numbers which not duplicate in each row and columns , and not change the position index , just fill the 0 number

Comment: Can you give a concrete example of an input, expected output, and the code you've tried?

Comment: i just edited it

Comment: Zum, really need you to post the desired output for a negative/postive.